# Django model wih a ForeignKey pointing to a salesforce model

Tags: django, salesforce, django-salesforce

I am using `django-salesforce` and I would like to create a model within Django that has a `ForeignKey` field pointing to a SFDC model (hosted on force.com).

I created a custom model on force.com, let us call it `SFModel`, and I can successfully work on it from django (CRUD) by subclassing `salesforce.models.Model`.

I also created a `django.db.models.Model`, let us call it `DJModel`, that has a unique field `ForeignKey(SFModel)`. This model is registered on the admin panel.

All models validate and I can go to my admin panel to try to create a new instance of `DJModel`. However, when I try to display the create_form in the admin I get the following error :

```
hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

and the debug stream says

[image]

So I tried to set an arbitrary alias to the SF entry in the `DATABASES` of my `settings.py`. There is a dedicated variable for that :

```
SALESFORCE_DB_ALIAS = 'youralias'
```

But I still have the same problem.

Any recommendation?

Comment: It is similar to support for multiple databases in Django, with standard backends like Postgres or MySQL. You can not create a ForeignKey e.g. from Postgres to MySQL. Even ForeignKeys between different different databases of the same type can not be created.

I recommend something similar to [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). If you find a solution that works between two standard databases, I can help you to find a solution that works between a standard database and Salesforce.

Comment: I recommend to close this question, because it is a feature unsupported by Django, not be reproduced neither on the current versions or the versions used that time, currently obsoleted.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't support it and an external reference to Salesforce should be currently saved as a CharField and a reference to other databases as IntegerField.

Django docs about [Limitations of multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases):

> **Django doesn’t** currently provide any **support** for foreign key or many-to-many **relationships spanning multiple databases**. If you have used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be internal to a single database.

I tried the cross reference with sqlite as 'default' database. It was possible to create an object of model DJModel with cross-database reference from sqlite to Salesforce. It behaves similarly to normal Django cross-database references, without obscure errors and only a dot reference can be used.

EDIT: Simplified after many years.